# Передать параметр в expect скрипт

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp, expect

Не получаеться передать параметр в скрипт `expect`

```
#./script.sh db.sql.gz
```

script.sh:

```
spawn scp -rp $1 user1@192.168.0.1:/home/folder/backup
expect {
password: {send "$pass\r"; exp_continue}
}
```

Подскажите как можно передать имя файла параметром при запуске скрипта, возможно ли это сделать по маске?

Comment: откройте для себя [sshpass](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sshpass), чтоб не использовать программу expect в роли костыля.

Comment: А шебанг у Вас в `./script.sh` какой, часом не `#!/bin/bash` или `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: именно `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Так у вас синтаксис под `#!/usr/bin/expect -f` Если очень хочется экспекта, погуглите как его в баш скрипт впихнуть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Старый дообрый **expect**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --

set usage "Usage: $argv0 file\n"
set user "username"
set host "hostname"
set pass "yourpass"
set dist_path "/remote/path"

if {$argc != 1} {
    puts $usage
    exit 1
}

set file [ lindex $argv 0 ]
puts $file

proc sendfile { file user host dist_path pass } {
    spawn scp -rp $file $user@$host:$dist_path
    expect_after {
        timeout { catch { close }; wait; return 1 }
        eof { catch { close }; wait; return 1 }
    }
    expect {
        ".+asswor.*" {send  "$pass\r"; exp_continue}
    }
    expect eof
}

sendfile $file $user $host $dist_path $pass

# End of script
```

Из доументации:

> Optional args are constructed into a list and stored in the variable
>   named argv.  argc is initialized to the
>          length of argv.

В принципе, если знакомы с C/Python там аргументы командной строки так же передаются

- argv - вектор аргументов
- argc - количество аргументов

Советую глянуть в сторону **pexpect**

Answer (score 1):

А вообще, судя по всему, движ в локалке происходит. Так-что попробуйте

```
ssh-copy-id -i user1@192.168.0.1  # один раз и навсегда !!! не в скрипте
```

а потом уже

```
scp -rp $1 user1@192.168.0.1:/home/folder/backup
```

без танцев с бубном (экспектом). Можно будет с вашей машины и вашей учетки из любого скрипта, или просто из шела, открывать ssh сесси для `user1@192.168.0.1` без ввода пароля.

> Но если машина, куда заливаете backup, не ваша, то лучше воспользуйтесь советом от Alexandr Barakin

**Но если прям очень хочется экспекта, то вот нашел. Прямо Ваш случай:**

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh user@192.168.1.10; expect "Password:" {send -- "password\r"}; expect "user@" {send "cat /etc/issue\r"};'
```

[Взято отсюда](http://www.tech-notes.net/use-expect-in-bash/)

Comment: это не в локале, просто заменил IP. sshpass пробовал но он отругался на использование маски имен.

Comment: А можно вывод `sshpass` с ошибкой глянуть?

Comment: Впринципе, ssh-copy-id наплевать, в локалке машина или нет, просто тут некоторые товарищи в сетях сильно беспокоятся об ставленном на чужой машине pub key, и я не могу с ними спорить ибо не специалист по безопасности. На своих машинах везде через ключ настроено

Comment: `root@server:/home/backup# sshpass -p 'qwwerrerert' scp -r user@196.117.0.192:/home/backup *.gz
backup-01-08-2018_15-25-29.sql.gz: Not a directory

root@server:/home/backup# sshpass -p 'qwwerrerert' scp user@196.117.0.192:/home/backup *.gz
scp: /home/backup: not a regular file`

Comment: `/home/backup *.gz` должна выглядеть так `/home/backup/*.gz` Как мне кажется или у вас в подпапках есть еще архивы которые нужно закачать на сервер? Просто в любом случае так как Вы написали работать не должно

Comment: Вы бы лучше задачу описали, подробно, а там бы и решение нашлось